# How to add name dynamically when pushing data to firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm tying to push data to firebase database, I want to push dynamic name and dynamic value to database. I'm using javascript.

```
function dbsave(Url){ 
var time = new Date().getTime();
firebase.database().ref('Usersfiles/' +window.logedinuser.uid ).set({
  time : Url /*here it is taking time as a string but i want it to take it as var time which is a var contains value */
  }, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("failed "+error);
      failedlol();

    } else {
      console.log("success");
    }
  });
}
```

I want to push both name and it's value dynamically.
like every time a user submits a data, then the time(which is name) should change and value too.

Comment: is the code working with updating the time so far?

Comment: time is not taken from var time = new Date().getTime(); it is taking time has a string (only the word 'time').  @KamanaKisinga

Answer (score 0):

simply change the code snippet as below

```js
function dbsave(Url) {
  var time = new Date().getTime();
  firebase.database().ref('Usersfiles/' + window.logedinuser.uid).set({
    time: time /*here it is taking time as a string but i want it to take it as var time which is a var contains value */
  }, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("failed " + error);
      failedlol();

    } else {
      console.log("success");
    }
  });
}
```

The reason it's not working is because time is only used as a property name
To get it to take in the variable 'time', assign this value to the property

Comment: yes, but i want that property should be dynamic.

so, i used [time] it considered it as verable.

BTW Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function dbsave(Url) {
  var time = new Date().getTime();
  firebase.database().ref('Usersfiles/' + window.logedinuser.uid).set({
 /*add [] to make it as verable*/   [time]: time /*here it is taking time as a string but i want it to take it as var time which is a var contains value */
  }, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("failed " + error);
      failedlol();

    } else {
      console.log("success");
    }
  });
}
```

i changed "time: time"  to "[time]: time"